# Drawing $y(t)$ graphs based on given information

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble with this question:

[image]

I know that the long-term behavior of $\frac{dy}{dt}$ $\to$ $\infty$ as $y$ increases, but do I go about drawing a $y$ versus $t$ graph? All I know, so far, is that when $y = -3,2,3$ $\implies$ $\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$. Please refrain from using plotting websites like Desmos; I prefer plotting this by hand for practice, if possible.

Comment: For starters, try to figure out where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is positive, negative, and also where $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ is negative/positive (concavity)

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dt} > 0$ when $-3 < y < 2$ and $y > 3$. $\frac{dy}{dt} < 0$ when $ y < -3$ and $2 < y < 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zeros of $dy/dt$ imply extremal values:

$t=-3$: Is a minimum because the slope changes from negative to positive.

$t=+2$: Is a maximum because the slope changes from positive to negative.

$t=+3$: Is a minimum because the slope changes from negative to positive.

The extremal values of $dy/dt$ indicate inflection points. We have one somewhere between $t=-2$ and $t=-1$ and we have another inflecion point at approximately $t=2.5$.

The function comes from $+\infty$ from the negative real axis and blows up to infinity for $t\to \infty$.

In order to get an approximation to the function you could use

$$dy/dt=a(t+3)(t-2)(t-3)$$

in combination with $dy/dt(t=0)\approx 3.5$ to obtain

$$dy/dt\approx\dfrac{7}{36}(t-2)(t^2-9).$$

Integrate this expression to obtain an approximation to $y(t)$

$$y(t)\approx \int \dfrac{7}{36}(t-2)(t^2-9)dt+c$$

The constant of integration indicates that $y(t)$ is not unique.